# I am unable to enforce tagging for ec2 instances. what am I missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, amazon-iam

I am attempting to force users to tag ec2 instances upon creation. I have set up a test account and have attached a policy that should require them to tag an ec2 instance when they create one.
When I log into the test account using a cognito window and attempt to create an ec2 instance, I am NOT required to tag the instance.

I have diligently through the stack Overflow Forums and via online searching in general. The answers I have come across all make sense but simply do not work.

The below IAM policy is what I have been working with. I have been modifying and experimenting to no avail.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:123456789:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:123456789:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:123456789:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:123456789:key-pair/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:123456789:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:123456789:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "environment",
                        "webserver"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:123456789:*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "RunInstances"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't get any error messages. When creating the ec2 instance with the test user account, I am simply allowed to proceed.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

I confirm your policy is not working. 
(all commands were run on `eu-west-1`)

```
$ aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0bbc25e23a7640b9b --instance-type t3.micro

{
    "Groups": [],
    "Instances": [
        {
            "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
            "ImageId": "ami-0bbc25e23a7640b9b",
            "InstanceId": "i-0f695dcb8044ef708",
...
```

I switched to this policy copy pasted from [our blog](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-policy-tags-restrict/) (the only difference I can see is that there is no account ID explicitly mentioned)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowToDescribeAll",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRunInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRunInstancesWithRestrictions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume",
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "key1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreateTagsOnlyLaunching",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "RunInstances"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I tried to start an instances without tags

```
$ aws --profile test ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0bbc25e23a7640b9b --instance-type t3.micro
```

or just tagging the instance, not the volume

```
$ aws --profile test ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0bbc25e23a7640b9b --instance-type t3.micro --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=key1,Value=production}]'
```

and both calls failed.

```
An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the RunInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Then I tried with both tag (any value)

```
$ aws --profile test ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0bbc25e23a7640b9b --instance-type t3.micro --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=key1,Value=value1}]' 'ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=key1,Value=value1}]'
```

and it worked !

```
{
    "Groups": [],
    "Instances": [
        {
            "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
            "ImageId": "ami-0bbc25e23a7640b9b",
            "InstanceId": "i-04aa7bd64b5f2ed22",
...
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I am still experiencing the same behavior in that my test user is allowed to create ec2 instances without creating any tags whatsoever.

Comment: I just reproduced this on my account (sorry for having tested **after** having replied)  I am testing your policy. I am searching the root cause

Comment: Thank you Sebastien. This information in your update is even more useful. I sincerely appreciate the help. I'm marking your answer as correct and up voting it.